# Erro lendo arquivo csv em Python

Tags: python, pandas

Ao ler um arquivo `.csv` em python gera o erro abaixo. O arquivo é muito grande e não consigo abrir. Alguém sabe como proceder e que erro é esse ?

```
import pandas as pd
dados = pd.read_csv('nell.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep=";")
```

Erro

```
........

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-00e18ff698ec> in <module>()
----> 1 dados = pd.read_csv('nell.csv', encoding='utf-8')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, doublequote, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    676                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    677 
--> 678         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    679 
    680     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    444 
    445     try:
--> 446         data = parser.read(nrows)
    447     finally:
    448         parser.close()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1034                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
   1035 
-> 1036         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1037 
   1038         # May alter columns / col_dict

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1846     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1847         try:
-> 1848             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1849         except StopIteration:
   1850             if self._first_chunk:

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 218, saw 4
```

Answer (score 0):

De acordo o seu log de erro, o parser está tendo problemas na linha 218 quando ele espera apenas 1 campo com dados (1 célula na linguagem do `.csv`) e está recebendo 4.

Consigo pensar em 2 soluções: A primeira seria ignorando o Header do arquivo, assim o Pandas vai criar quantos índices forem necessários para cada linha. Para fazer isso é só adicionar `header=None` na instrução que carrega e configura o arquivo `.csv`

```
import pandas as pd
dados = pd.read_csv('nell.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep=";", header=None)
```

Outra solução, mais arriscada é verdade, é **ignorar** todas as linhas que derem erro. Assim, ao invés de adicionar o parâmetro do `header` adicione o `error_bad_lines`.

```
import pandas as pd
dados = pd.read_csv('nell.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep=";", error_bad_lines=False)
```

Novamente: com esse segunda configuração você vai ignorar todas as linhas com erro. Sugiro a primeira, mas postei a segunda a título de conhecimento.